# Making map more interactive

Tags: qgis, javascript, features, qgis2web

I have created a map using QGIS and I am planning to put it online using QGIS2Web. However, QGIS2Web does not provide much options of making the map interactive. One of my goals is that when a user hovers over a specific portion (region) of my map (similar to the map here: https://www.ethnologue.com/region/Africa), that region of the map gets highlighted and a popup appears showing info about that region. Users can also click on that region which makes the map to focus on that region. My map is about Africa as well.

Below is how my map looks like so far:

[image: Screenshot of my map]

By now I have added popups and a second search engine (allowing users to search for a specific country, region) on my map. I have searched the website to see if I can find any resource on how to do it, but I have not found anything yet.

Comment: It depends how you are going to deploy your map. You will likely need to write that functionality in JavaScript using the OpenLayers or [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup) API

Comment: @Matt I will likely use Leaflet API. Do you know what JavaScript library or package I must use?

Comment: It really depends on what functionality you need. From what you describe in your question then Leaflet can handle most, if not all, of what you want. There are some great [plugins for Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) that extend its capabilities too.